# Simple Registration displays error on registration

Tags: members, registration

Whenever a sign up occurs, this is displayed:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '45' for key 'PRIMARY':
```

INSERT INTO `exp_member_data` (`member_id`) VALUES ('45')

The membership is created, but the email isn't sent.

Answer (score 1):

Upon deeper research we found this documented bug to be the cause of our problem: https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/21861/registering-a-member-via-member_registerregister_member-will-throw-a-mysql-

Updating to EE 3.3.3 resolved the issue for us.